# jquery jscrollpane destroy then recreate/reinitialize

Tags: jquery, jquery-jscrollpane

I can initialize jScrollPane by following code.

```
$("#scroll-pane").jScrollPane();
```

And can reinitialized with `reinitialize` function. It all works fine.

But I have a feature in my page when user resize window as width as low `480px` (mobile mode) I will need to destroy `$("#scroll-pane")` jScrollPane. I can destroy it with:

```
$("#scroll-pane").data('jsp').destroy();
```

This works too. But when I resize back to desktop size window following code don't work.

```
$("#scroll-pane").jScrollPane();
```

Any idea? Any workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When initializing the **jscrollpane** for the first time, this would work

`$("#scroll-pane").jScrollPane();`

but after destroying the instance of jscrollpane if you need to re-initialize you need to call like this

`$("#scroll-pane").jScrollPane().data().jsp`

Check out the Live Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/j3nE3/178/